# Books in Dr.A's house

Tags: logical-deduction

Dr. A claims that reading is his favorite pastime. "There is at least one book in my house," he told the audience the day before yesterday. "There are more books in my house than 999," he said yesterday. "There are fewer books in my house than 1000," he said today. He only spoke the truth for one day, it is known. Dr. a has how many books at home?

Comment: I've removed several tags which were not relevant to this puzzle. For example, [tag:logic-grid] is for grid puzzles like sudoku, and [tag:calculation-puzzle] is for puzzles that revolve around numerical calculations. Please take the time to read the descriptions of the tags when you choose them.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dr. A has a whopping

> zero books

in his house, since that is the only number possible if he lies on 2 of the days.

He told the truth on day

> 3, possibly out of guilt from lying on the first 2 days.

Comment: Assuming that no books entered or left his house between those statements. Without that assumption, I don't think we can deduce anything. / Derivation of the solution: The second and third statements contradict each other, so one must be true, so the first statement must be false. / Maybe Dr. A is more into magazines?

Comment: @EdMurphy But I think that is a fair assumption. If it were not so, then the whole puzzle becomes overly technical, incomplete and annoying.

Comment: hum interesting. But how you logically reach that claim? I use a graphing calculator to draw a set which is represented by a number axis. The first sentence is the from 1 to the right, the second sentence is greater than 999, and the third sentence is the line segment less than 1000. It is false to cover twice, and only 0 is covered once. So the doctor's family is 0 books. However, i think this is a trick, rather the logic way to solve it.